# setData raises exit code -1073741819

Tags: python, pyside, exit-code, qstandarditemmodel

I have a subclass of QtGui.QStandardItemModel with  setData as follow:

```
def setData(self, index, value, role):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.EditRole:
        old = self.itemFromIndex(index).text()
        new = value
        MAIN.changeItem(old,new,index)
    return QtGui.QStandardItemModel.setData(self, index, value, role)
```

In MAIN.changeItem I take the 'old' value and replace it with the 'new' in the Database and and then I setData with the return value. And finally I refresh the Model to show the result. Like so:

```
def changeItem(self,old,new,index):

    dosomethin(old,newindex) # adjust the database and model

    self.tableUpdate() # refresh/redraw the table
```

But I'm getting exit -1073741819, but only if I do them one after the other. If I don't refresh the model(commenting out the self.tableUpdate()) but instead do something else that would normaly refresh it(like adding a new item, or changing tabs), it doesn't raise the error. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Is `MAIN` related to Qt in any way?

Comment: Yes, it's the whole application class instance.

Comment: Is the error code raised by Qt or the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh figured out.

I thought the process would go like:

```
model.itemChanged.signal -> databaseUpdate() -> setItem() -> tableUpdate()
```

But instead it was doing:

```
model.itemChanged.signal -> databaseUpdate() -> tableUpdate() -> setItem()
```

And since setItem was looking for a index item which was not there anymore(because it got updated), it crashed.

Fixed it by changing the setData return to 'True', or anything.