# Visual Studio Crashes when trying to connect to SQL Database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2013

I've been developing an application In VB.net for the past few months using Visual Studio 2013 Pro and Azure Cloud Services.  Thursday when I went to run / debug the application I got an exception vshost32.exe has stopped working.  After hours of research, trial and error I was unable to fix it.  I uninstalled VS and re-installed it.  No Luck :( 
I was then frustrated to the point that I wiped my computer, Formatted the hard drives and Installed a clean version of Windows 7 Ultimate and VS Pro 2013.  My application still does the same thing.. any idea what the heck is going on here?  I have changed the debugger to x86 followed hundreds of solutions online with no luck.

I have now started another application but when I connect to my Azure Files then try to connect to the DB in SQL Server Explorer within VS it literally just crashes Visual Studio goes into debug mode then restarts.  I have tried disabling my Firewall and Virus Protection.  Can anyone point me in the right direction, I'm bummed right out as it seems I have an application which was nearing completion that is now unusable...

Thanks in advance to Everyone for your help and replies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you encounter the problem when you debug it? I had the same problem when I was debugging it by pressing F11 key when the debugger point is at the sql statement. If you have the same problem, then try debugging it with F10 key.

Comment: Originally I was, yes.  Now I cannot even create the connection between Visual Studio and the Azure Database.  Every few tries I end up with an error "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occured during the login process.(provider: SSl Provider, error: 0 - The message received was unexpected or badly formatted.)  I went on azure and logged into the DB to double check my Username and Password to validate the information I am supplying is correct.

Comment: Between hitting F5, F9, F11 It either throws "vshost32.exe Has stopped working" or "The program '[2740] Citrus Quality Management Studio.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'."

Comment: Not sure if [#this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451176/setdata-raises-exit-code-1073741819) link helps

Comment: Thanks for your responses but no solution yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I also have the problem to connect remote database a month ago. Each time I connect to the remote database, the application (VisualStudio/SSMS) crashed. After reserching, I found the [solution](https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2915689/en-us) for my case.
The source of my problem are:

- Visual Studio 2013 or .NET Framework 4.5.1 installed
- Some network anaylyzing / detecting tools installed

I don't know whether you are the same case. You can check the link for details.